# Need to fix the formula here for Moving Average

Tags: excel, analytics, moving-average

I've tried creating a system wherein you can get 6 days average on the 6th cell, 10 days 10th cell.

However, the problem I'm facing here is that when I type 7 for example in the cell I2, It provides me the average for data from Cells E5 to E11 whereas I was expecting the average from E3 to E9.

Similarly I'd like my sheet to provide me the average for the cells E3 through E12 on the 10th column or the cell K12, but it gives me an average from E8:E17. I know I have messed up, please help. [image]
[My file is here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1aZ-4Fn9z2uSq-Rpn3AvAhx84mljPT1-z)

Comment: Someone please tell

Answer (score 3):

If you want the formula to count from `E3`, then you must specify the appropriate range:

```
=IF(ROW()<$I$2+2,"",AVERAGE(OFFSET(E3:E2999,0,0,$I$21)))
```

If you want the range does not change when you copy the formula, fix it with a `$` sign:

```
=IF(ROW()<$I$2+2,"",AVERAGE(OFFSET($E$3:$E$2999,0,0,$I$2,1)))
```

Note that `OFFSET` is a volatile function, it may be better to use `INDEX`:

```
=IF(ROW()<$I$2+2,"",AVERAGE($E$3:INDEX($E$3:$E$2999,$I$2)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, @basic for answering my query, but I searched further and figured if I had used the OFFSET, correctly, serves my purpose

Here particularly all I needed to do was

  -

```
=IF(ROW()<$I$2+2,"",AVERAGE(OFFSET(E3,0,0,-$I$2,1)))
```

Thanks buddy